# Inno Setup change Task Manager Description for Setup.tmp

Tags: inno-setup

I already suspect it is not possible and likely to be hardcoded, requiring modification of the Inno Setup source code, however Inno Setup is extremely flexible, so maybe there is a way?

Is it possible to change what is displayed in the Windows Task Manager Description field for Setup.tmp that runs with Setup.exe, from 'Setup\Uninstall' to something else?

[image: Inno Setup Task Manager Setup.tmp Description]

I have already checked if this is one of the default messages that can be modified.

If not possible directly in Inno Setup, as I suspect, would modifying the resources with something like [Resource Hacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker) or [Resource Tuner](http://www.restuner.com) make this possible? Alternatively, is there another esoteric way of doing this without modifying the Inno Setup source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to edit the "Version Info" of the `Setup.e32` using a tool like [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/).

```
1 VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION 51,1052,0,0
PRODUCTVERSION 0,0,0,0
FILEOS 0x4
FILETYPE 0x1
{
BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
{
    BLOCK "000004B0"
    {
        VALUE "FileDescription", "Setup/Uninstall of My Program"
        VALUE "FileVersion", "51.1052.0.0"
    }
}

BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
{
    VALUE "Translation", 0x0000 0x04B0
}
}
```

[image: Setup name]

Comment: Could you tell me what `Setup.e32` is and how to access it? If I open Setup.exe in Resource Hacker, all I see for the File Description is what is displayed by Setup.exe. Maybe I should be asking this in a new question?

Comment: The `Setup.e32` is part of Inno Setup installation.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Found it in the install directory.