# Inno Setup: Change file description

Tags: windows, inno-setup, fileversioninfo

I'm using Inno Setup 5, and to enbody an customizable .exe file, it's name is changed in the `[Files]` section using the parameter `DestName`. But, we're talking about an .exe file.

I noticed that when it's running, the name in Task Manager is the old file name, the `DestName` parameter only changes it's actual name, not the file `Description`, which is shown in Task Manager. Somebody has had any experience like this?

I'm using Windows 10, running as administrator (if makes any difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file description is a part of the file header.

You cannot change it easily. It's possible. But only with unsigned binaries. Changing a description of a signed binary would invalidate the signature, as any other change would. And nowadays all binaries should be signed.

---

If you sign the binary as part of the installer build, you can modify the description before that. You can use [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) command-line. There are various way to invoke a tool like Resource Hacker as part of the installer build:

- If you build your installer from command-line, you can modify the description even before you run the Inno Setup compiler. See [Run a [Code] or PowerShell script in Inno Setup compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48772183/850848).
- You can use [`Exec` preprocessor function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=exec). This is also covered in [Run a [Code] or PowerShell script in Inno Setup compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48772183/850848).
- Or you can do it as part of the signing. For some information see [Inno Setup - How to change the icon of the shortcut of uninstaller without separate icon file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44522001/850848)  and [Microsoft SmartScreen - suspended using Inno Setup installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29067877/850848).

---

For an example on how to use Resource Hacker to modify a binary description, see [Inno Setup change Task Manager Description for Setup.tmp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41404904/850848) – It's about a manual modification, but you will need some of the information even for your automated (command-line) modification.

---

*Though I believe that way easier is to automate and customize your application build process, so you can easily produce the binaries with custom description, instead of hacking it into the installer build process.*

Answer (score 1):

**[Setup]: VersionInfoDescription**

**Default value:** "*AppName* Setup" if *AppName* doesn't include constants, an empty string otherwise

**Description:**
Specifies the file description value for the Setup version info.
This setting has no effect if *UseSetupLdr* is set to *no*.

**Code Sample:**

VersionInfoDescription = "This is my awesome app description"

Comment: Supposedly this setup information is never used, and so are VersionInfoCopyright and others. At least I can't find them anywhere in the Windows control center, or in the Registry entry.

Answer (score -3):

There is a solution I found.
Go to the direction of Inno Setup, then open `Default.isl` file. This file includes all setup descriptions & other components.
You can open this file with any text editor, then press `Ctrl + F` and search for whatever you want to change.
After you saved this file, compile your setup file and execute it again.
My description was already changed.
There is an example I did previously.

[image]

Comment: The question is about changing description of the installed files, not any description in the installer. And for changing description in the installer, there are better ways. Not editing a file that is part of Inno Setup installation, which gets overwritten everytime you upgrade Inno Setup.